# why does atom not know the period

Tags: java

I'm trying to code java using atom, how do I fix the below error?
I would really appreciate some help.
some links to other cute tutorials can help too.

it says

Testing.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
label.setText = "Testing";
     ^
  symbol:   variable setText
  location: variable label of type JLabel
Testing.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
frame.addComponents(label);
     ^
  symbol:   method addComponents(JLabel)
  location: variable frame of type JFrame
Testing.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
frame.setVisibility(true);
     ^
  symbol:   method setVisibility(boolean)
  location: variable frame of type JFrame
3 errors
[Finished in 0.507s]

how do I fix this?
here are the necessary lines of code

```
label.setText = "Testing"; (1st error line)
frame.addComponents(label); (2nd error line)
frame.setVisibility(true); (3rd error line)
```

Comment: The best fix is to read a basic introductory Java textbook since you're guessing at some pretty important fundamentals, and learning by guessing is not a sound strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If you took a look at the javadoc for JLabel, you'd see that you should actually be doing:

```
label.setText("Testing");
```

Also, it should be `frame.setVisible(true)`... where are you getting your info from?